# Unable to switch from InProcess to OutOfProcess ASP.NET Core hosting mode in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

As part of a test (mixing Windows auth with JWT auth) I'd like to see how my application behaves using OutOfProcess hosting mode. Looking at my published output, I see that the only difference is in web.config in the aspNetCore tag (setting hostingModel to either InProcess or OutOfProcess).

but, when I change the value from InProcess to OutOfProcess and relaunch the website and look at the headers returned when I make a request, I see the following header in both cases

Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0

Thus, I'm concluding that out of process hosting doesn't take as I'm supposed to get a Kestrel as I get when I self-host

Server: Kestrel

So, what am I missing?

Comment: When hosting on IIS, in process or out of process, the Server header should reflect IIS (IIS is the actual server talking to the browser). You never should expect Kestrel in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you set the  hosting mode to OutOfProcess, the response header will become the  Kestrel. I have created a test demo on my side and it worsk well. Could you please post more details information about the self-host or framework dependency.

My web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\donet.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="OutOfProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: When I create a repro project from scratch, leaving everything default (new .NET Core 3.11 ASP.NET API project, publish to folder and deploy on my IIS), I see the correct behavior. My web.config matches yours (except arguments of course), I only have stdoutLogEnabled = true. And I have this additional section inside system.webServers because I need windows auth

   <security>
  <authentication>
    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
  </authentication>
   </security>

Comment: interestingly enough, if I removed the security section, things started to work. My appconfig.json needed some additional work (seems to be using the urls for Kestrel if they're configured so I Had to remove them), but I'm now seeing the Kestrel as server header instead of IIS.